SwiftUI "mask" left and right portions of a view
I have a rounded rectangle and I wish to mask the left and right portions of it (whose widths can be custom defined as State variables). What I want is the rounded rectangle to preserve it's rounded rect shape as I apply left and right masks. I say mask for the sake of explanation but the actual implementation may not to use .mask modifier if create issues in hit testing for gesture recognizers on the whole view.
Here is the code to mask the left and right portions of a rounded rectangle.
struct MaskTesting: View {

  @State var rectWidth:CGFloat = 300
  @State var leftMaskWidth:CGFloat = 100
  @State var rightMaskWidth:CGFloat = 100

  var body: some View {
    
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.orange)
        .frame(maxHeight:70)
        .frame(width: rectWidth)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.purple)
                .frame(maxHeight:70)
                .frame(width: leftMaskWidth)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.purple)
                .frame(maxHeight:70)
                .frame(width: rightMaskWidth)
                .offset(x:rectWidth - 100)
        }
    
}

The output is something like this. But I want the main orange view to be rounded rectangle than a plain rectangle in the output. How do I implement it in SwiftUI?


Have you tried using a RoundedRectangle with horizontal padding?

@BenzyNeez I haven’t tried actually as the rectangle here is just a sample view. In real code, I have an ‘HStack’ of images instead of rectangle. I want to mask part of that view left and right and maintain the rounded rect shape of the main view.

@BenzyNeez How do I apply padding to clipShape?

You can use a custom shape. Answer updated to show how.

A RoundedRectangle as mask would seem like the most obvious solution:
Rectangle()
    .fill(.orange)
    .frame(maxHeight: 70)
    .frame(width: rectWidth)
    .mask {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .padding(.leading, leftMaskWidth)
            .padding(.trailing, rightMaskWidth)
    }
    .background(.purple)

However, you say this is not possible, because it doesn't work for hit testing. So here are two other possible techniques.

1. Use .blendMode
The effect of a mask can also be achieved using .blendMode. In particular,  blend mode .destinationOut can be used to "cut out" a form from an underlying view. The "scope" of the blend mode needs to be constrained by applying .compositingGroup, otherwise it goes on burning into lower layers:
Rectangle()
    .fill(.orange)
    .frame(maxHeight: 70)
    .frame(width: rectWidth)
    .overlay {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .padding(.leading, leftMaskWidth)
            .padding(.trailing, rightMaskWidth)
            .blendMode(.destinationOut)
            .background(.purple)
            .compositingGroup()
    }



2. Use a custom Shape as clip shape
An alternative approach is to define a custom Shape, which can then be used as clip shape:
struct CustomClipShape: Shape {
    let leftMaskWidth: CGFloat
    let rightMaskWidth: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path(
            roundedRect: CGRect(
                x: rect.minX + leftMaskWidth,
                y: rect.minY,
                width: rect.width - leftMaskWidth - rightMaskWidth,
                height: rect.height
            ),
            cornerRadius: 5
        )
    }
}

Rectangle()
    .fill(.orange)
    .frame(maxHeight: 70)
    .frame(width: rectWidth)
    .clipShape(
        CustomClipShape(
            leftMaskWidth: leftMaskWidth,
            rightMaskWidth: rightMaskWidth
        )
    )
    .background(.purple)

The result looks the same as before.
Regarding hit testing, the area that is receptive to hit testing can be constrained by setting the same shape as .contentShape too:
.contentShape(
    CustomClipShape(
        leftMaskWidth: leftMaskWidth,
        rightMaskWidth: rightMaskWidth
    )
)


If these techniques do not resolve the hit testing issue then perhaps you can elaborate more on exactly what the issue is, so that this can be addressed as the main problem.

@DeepakSharma Regarding hit testing, it might help to set the custom shape as .contentShape too, answer updated to include mention of this

Does contentShape preserve hit testing area or it reduces hit testing area with padding?

@DeepakSharma My understanding is that it simply defines the area for hit testing, at least, that's what the documentation says. This might be a reduced part of the original area (so it works like a clip shape for hit testing) or it could make areas sensitive to hit testing that weren't before. Note that there is another variant of this modifier that takes a ContentShapeKinds as parameter, see contentShape(_:_:eoFill:).

Is it possible to have the custom shape path filled with a custom chosen color having alpha value?

@DeepakSharma It depends what you are using the custom shape for. If for a clip shape or content shape: these are pure shapes, there is no fill involved. If for a mask: yes, this could be filled using a color with alpha. So perhaps you can try using a .mask in combination with .contentShape?
